# Sort values within dataframe grouped by multiple columns

Tags: python, sorting, pandas, group-by

I have a dataframe that is in this form.

```
 Type  Major   GPA   
  F      A     2.6   
  T      B     3.4   
  T      C     2.9   
  F      A     1.8   
  T      B     2.8   
  F      C     3.5 
 ...
```

I'd like to group the Dataframe ("students") by `Type` and `Major`, count the number of rows for each grouping, then sort from most to least popular majors for each type, and, finally, create a new dataframe that includes the 20 most popular majors.

I'd like the output to look like this:

```
F   
A 21  
B 19  
C 15
...
T  
A 14  
B 7  
C 3
```

This is what I did:

```
most_popular = students.groupby(['Type', 'Major']).size().sort_values(ascending=False)[:20]
```

But what this does is sort across both Types - rather than sort separately for each.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The results are sorted automatically as a default argument.  Is this the desired output?

```
>>> df.groupby(['Type', 'Major'], as_index=False).GPA.count().sort_values(['Major', 'GPA'])
  Type Major  GPA
0    F     A    2
2    T     B    2
1    F     C    1
3    T     C    1
```

Comment: Unfortunately no.  It's sorting the results by Major - alphabetical order rather than by GPA.

Answer (score 1):

```
most_popular = students.groupby(['Type', 'Major']).size().reset_index().sort_values(['Type', 'Major'], ascending=[True, False])[:20]
```

The key is to sort in both ASC and DSC order, you can use:

```
.sort_values(['Type', 'Major'], ascending=[True, False])
```